# Flexbox Footer Wrap Not Expanding

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to set up my flexbox for responsiveness and accessibility. However as can be seen in the attached images, for some reason text is lost when reducing screen size.

[Image of webpage at full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7co23.jpg)
[Image of reduced size & clashing elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2sYZ.png)

```
/* Footer Styling Definitions */
footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
}

#footer_left {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_centre {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_right {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.logo_footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.legal {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.legal_stuff {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.legal_stuff:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    section {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    section {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .label {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

I would love some assistance - sorry I am just new to web development so I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Welcome to SO! instead of an image you should consider using snippets, through which we can check your console or maybe if any problem in the html or javascipt

Comment: Can you share your HTML and JS code too?

Comment: @SatoTakeru I am only beginner in web development I haven't learnt JS yet.

Comment: @RoboPYJS snippets attached :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can help you.

This is my screenshot image.
[image: This is my image.]
[image: Do you mean here?]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&family=Comfortaa&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap');

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    /*font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;*/
    height: 100vh;
}

p {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
    
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
}

/* Navigation Styling Definitions */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.70);
    z-index: 101; 
}

nav ul {    
    display: flex;
}

nav li {
    flex: 1;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline underline;
    color: darkslategray;
}

/* Header Styling Definitions */
header {
    background-image: url("images/sunset-1645103.jpeg");
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.logo_header {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Section Styling Definitions */
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.phone {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.phone:hover {
    color: darkslategray;
}

.call_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
}

/* Aside Styling Definitions */
aside {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Article Styling Definitions */
article {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#article_left {
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#article_right {
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.cta {
    flex: 30;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}


.input-box {
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 150%;
}

/* Footer Styling Definitions */
footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
}

#footer_left {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_centre {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_right {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.logo_footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.legal {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.legal_stuff {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.legal_stuff:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    section {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    section {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .label {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" text="text/css">
<title>Summer Escapes | Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Main Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <lI><a href="index.html">Home</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></lI>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<!-- End Main Naigation -->
<!-- Page Header -->
    <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_header" src="images/sunset_escapes_logo.png" alt="Summer Escapes Logo" height="auto"></a>
    </header>
<!-- End Page Header -->
<!-- Main Content -->
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="article_left">
                <h2>Call Us!</h2>
                <img class="call_img" src="images/phone-icon-925.png">
                <h3>
                    <p>Want to speak to a human regarding our Summer Escapes reviews?</p>
                    <p>Maybe you have a review request?</p>
                    <p>Call us now!</p>
                    <p><a class="phone" href="tel:+61 412 345 678">+61 123 456 789</a></p>
                </h3>
                
            </div>
            <div id="article_right">
                <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
                <form id="contact_form">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_name">Full name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_phone">Mobile number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" placeholder="Mobile number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="E-mail address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>               
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact+message" style="resize: none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
<!-- End Main Content -->
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div id="footer_left">
            <p>Socials</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_centre">
            <img class="logo_footer" src="images/sunset_escapes_logo_inverted.png" alt="Summer Escapes Logo">
            <p>Copyright © 2021 Summer Escapes</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_right">
            <div class="legal">
                <a class="legal_stuff" href="#" target="new">Legal Stuff</a> | <a class="privacy_policy" href="#" target="new">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<!-- End Footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer. :)

Comment: Still gets cut off :-(

Comment: Did you tried to delete cache?

Comment: Yes https://imgur.com/a/MztUelL

Comment: So doesn't work?

Comment: Nope :( I also need to look at how to remove the white empty space from bottom of page.

Comment: Do you mean here?

Comment: Yes I mean there :-)

Comment: If you open the developer tool in your browser, you can find that there's nothing there. If you have some more content and the page is longer than the viewport height, the white space will disappear. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&family=Comfortaa&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap');

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    /*font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;*/
    height: 100vh;
}

p {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
    
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
}

/* Navigation Styling Definitions */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.70);
    z-index: 101; 
}

nav ul {    
    display: flex;
}

nav li {
    flex: 1;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline underline;
    color: darkslategray;
}

/* Header Styling Definitions */
header {
    background-image: url("images/sunset-1645103.jpeg");
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.logo_header {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Section Styling Definitions */
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.phone {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.phone:hover {
    color: darkslategray;
}

.call_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
}

/* Aside Styling Definitions */
aside {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Article Styling Definitions */
article {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#article_left {
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#article_right {
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.cta {
    flex: 30;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}


.input-box {
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 150%;
}

/* Footer Styling Definitions */
footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
}

#footer_left {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_centre {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#footer_right {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.logo_footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.legal {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.legal_stuff {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.privacy_policy:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.legal_stuff:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    section {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    section {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .label {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" text="text/css">
<title>Summer Escapes | Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Main Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <lI><a href="index.html">Home</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></lI>
            <lI><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></lI>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<!-- End Main Naigation -->
<!-- Page Header -->
    <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_header" src="images/sunset_escapes_logo.png" alt="Summer Escapes Logo" height="auto"></a>
    </header>
<!-- End Page Header -->
<!-- Main Content -->
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="article_left">
                <h2>Call Us!</h2>
                <img class="call_img" src="images/phone-icon-925.png">
                <h3>
                    <p>Want to speak to a human regarding our Summer Escapes reviews?</p>
                    <p>Maybe you have a review request?</p>
                    <p>Call us now!</p>
                    <p><a class="phone" href="tel:+61 412 345 678">+61 123 456 789</a></p>
                </h3>
                
            </div>
            <div id="article_right">
                <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
                <form id="contact_form">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_name">Full name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_phone">Mobile number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" placeholder="Mobile number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="E-mail address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>               
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact+message" style="resize: none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
<!-- End Main Content -->
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div id="footer_left">
            <p>Socials</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_centre">
            <img class="logo_footer" src="images/sunset_escapes_logo_inverted.png" alt="Summer Escapes Logo">
            <p>Copyright © 2021 Summer Escapes</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_right">
            <div class="legal">
                <a class="legal_stuff" href="#" target="new">Legal Stuff</a> | <a class="privacy_policy" href="#" target="new">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<!-- End Footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You answered your own question to share your knowledge. Can you add some details so that others can understand your issues and how did you solve them?

Comment: @SatoTakeru no the flex box still doesn't work as expected. The Legal Stuff | Privacy Policy keeps getting cut off instead of stacking correctly